# What is the 8 bits in a 8-bit Deep Neural Network?

Tags: compression, deep-learning, quantization, 8-bit

One consensus has recently been achieved in Deep Learning research community is that 8-bit parameters is usually enough for Deep Neural Networks to achieve decent results, which might own to the redundancy in DNNs and the robustness in DNNs that makes DNNs tolerate small variations. For example, a 32-bit fully trained CNN can simply be represented with 8-bit parameters.

Since 8 bits can be represented in a series of forms to represent various ranges in different precision:

- **unsigned int 8** that represents 256 unsigned integers,
- **8-bit float** that represents 256 unevenly sampled numbers with fractions,
- **8-bit fix point** .

**Question** is that what is the best choice of 8 bits that is actually used in the many mentioned 8-bit DNNs, and why is that the best choice.

Comment: I read a few abstracts of some of these papers and it seems like they are usually talking about 8 (or 16) bit floating arithmetic. Although one paper uses both [8 bit fixed point and 8 bit floating point arithmetic](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.03073.pdf). HTH.